# update mysql database using the submit button on the colorbox

Tags: php, mysql

Index page list all the data from mysql & have a edit link for each data. When clicking the edit link it popup edit page within colorbox. the colorbox contain 2 text fields & an update button.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.ajax').colorbox();
});
</script>
```

[image]

When clicking the submit button, updates the new data to mysql within the colorbox.

Please anyone help me on this..
thanks!

Comment: How did you show the content inside colorbox,Using ajax?

Comment: <a class='ajax' href='edit_data.php?id={$row['porperty_id']}' title='$row[porperty_short]'>Edit</a>

Comment: You can write normal php code to update in edit_data.php.What is the problem,Where you stuck/

Comment: if i load all the property in a single page, update work inside the colorbox. But when i try to list the property in the pagination the update process not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a simple to update this.
**First:** Get the data from html form.
**Second:** Send a request via `Ajax`.
**Third:** Update this using php.

**PHP CODE**

```
    <?php

$prop_adr = $_POST['property_Address']; // or whatever your variable
$prop_zip = $_POST['property_Zip']; // or whatever your variable

// provide the correct info in mysql_connect();
$sql =mysql_connect('mysql_server(localhost)','mysql_user(root)','mysql_pass(empty)');
$db = mysql_select_db('your database name',$sql);//provide the database name

// UPDATE you table.
mysql_query("UPDATE `table_name` SET `address` = '$prop_adr'
WHERE `zipcode` = '$prop_zip'");

    ?>
```

Comment: i will create a demo page for you hold on. so you can better understand

Comment: Please tell what is the exactly problem or paste the code that I figure out by self.

Comment: http://abhilashraj.com/test-php1/ check this link!

with pagination it not working correctly

Comment: I changed everyone it successfully changed.Provide more information to understanding.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30725/discussion-between-kannan-and-user2280065)